# Django email: was connection to SMTP server established?

Tags: django, smtp, django-email

What I try to check if the connection was already opened, and if not, open it. I do

`connection = mail.get_connection()`

`connection.open()`

to get the connection and open it. Then I send the emails and close it under some condition. Is there a way to check if the connection has already been opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection = mail.get_connection()
```

After this line, `connection` represents an `settings.EmailBackend` object

Check [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/69af4d09bae7782f733e01b19cf69fa6f36d7165/django/core/mail/__init__.py#L26)

And now your `connection` object has an attribute `connection` which represents connection is already open  or not

check [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/69af4d09bae7782f733e01b19cf69fa6f36d7165/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L34) and [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/69af4d09bae7782f733e01b19cf69fa6f36d7165/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L47)

So In general terms, logic will be

```
if connection.connection :
   # already open
else:
   # not open
```

Also I will add one point,

When you do `connection.open()`, django itself checks whether the connection is already open or not, and do things accordingly.

See [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/69af4d09bae7782f733e01b19cf69fa6f36d7165/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L47) from django's repo

Comment: Thank you! It answers my question in detail